# Dynamically create a find query and have it trigger helper

Tags: javascript, meteor

What I have is a collection.  By default the whole collection is shown on the page in a table.  The user can then narrow down the results by entering in filter data in 1 or multiple textboxes.

So I have spent the last several hours trying to make this work reactively but failing miserably.  The helper is below:

```
Template.localBoardTemplate.helpers({

    localDelivery: function (){
        return localBoardColl.find(query);  
    }
});
```

Now I have keyup events on the individual textboxes that all trigger the same function to dynamically build the query:

```
function loadBoardRecords(){
    var query = {}; 

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardTripNumSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['tripNumber'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardTripNumSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardLoadNumSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['orderLoadNum'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardLoadNumSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardEquipmentSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['equipmentTypeName'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardEquipmentSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardCustomerSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['Customer'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardCustomerSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardTrailerNumSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['trailerNum'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardTrailerNumSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }


    if($('input:text[name=localBoardPUCitySetting]').val() != ""){
        query['puCity'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardPUCitySetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardPUStateSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['puState'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardPUStateSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('#localBoardPUDateSetting').val() != ""){
        puDate = moment($('#localBoardPUDateSetting').val(), "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();
        query['puDate'] =  puDate;
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardDELCitySetting]').val() != ""){
        query['delCity'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardDELCitySetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardDELStateSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['delState'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardDELStateSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('#localBoardDELDateSetting').val() != ""){
        delDate = moment($('#localBoardDELDateSetting').val(), "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();
        query['delDate'] =  delDate;
    }
}
```

Now I have tried using a session variable to hold the query this failed because you can't have nested objects in the session variables.  I then tried a package called ReactiveObj and that I couldn't get working either.  Heck I even tried a ReactiveArr but that isn't reactive unless you .list it and that doesn't work for the query in the find.

This can't be this hard of a problem and I have probably overlooked something minor.  I am hoping someone can point me to the write package or solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this through a few bit more trial and error and the help of Thai Trans answer.  I used a reativevar variable to store an object. The correct code is as follows:

Helper:

```
Template.localBoardTemplate.helpers({
    localDelivery: function (){
        return localBoardColl.find(Template.instance().searchQuery.get());  
    }
});
```

The function that creates the query and stores it in the reacvtive-var:

```
function loadBoardRecords(template){
    var query = {}; 

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardTripNumSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['tripNumber'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardTripNumSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

            if($('input:text[name=localBoardPUStateSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['puState'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardPUStateSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('#localBoardPUDateSetting').val() != ""){
        puDate = moment($('#localBoardPUDateSetting').val(), "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();
        query['puDate'] =  puDate;
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardDELCitySetting]').val() != ""){
        query['delCity'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardDELCitySetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardDELStateSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['delState'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=localBoardDELStateSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    if($('#localBoardDELDateSetting').val() != ""){
        delDate = moment($('#localBoardDELDateSetting').val(), "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();
        query['delDate'] =  delDate;
    }


    template.searchQuery.set( query );
}
```

This works perfectly.  It also still allows for the reactive collection updates even during a users search.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-n-dirty code with `ReactiveVar`

```
var buildQuery = function(formId) {
   // put the code in the loadBoardRecords with the form id 
   // and return the query 

   return query;   
}

Template.layout.helpers({
    localDelivery: function (){
        return Template.instance()['resultSet'].get();  
    }
});

Template.layout.events({
  'click .searchButton': function() {
      var formId = $(...); // get the id for the form
      var cursor = localBoardColl.find(search(formId));

      Template.instance()['resultSet'].set(cursor);
  } 
});

Template.layout.created = function () {
   this['resultSet'] = new ReactiecVar(null);
}
```

Comment: Doing it this way would that still auto update the dom when a new item is added t the collection? From what I understand you are doing here is just polling the collection whenever the searchbutton is pressed and saving to a reactivevar the cursor.  What happens if another user adds something to the collection?  Will it react accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you CAN store nested objects in Session variable.

On helpers:

```
Template.localBoardTemplate.helpers({

    localDelivery: function (){
        var query = Session.get('QUERY') || {};
        return localBoardColl.find(query);  
    }

});
```

On events:

```
function loadBoardRecords(){
    var query = Session.get('QUERY') || {}; 

    if($('input:text[name=localBoardTripNumSetting]').val() != ""){
        query['tripNumber'] = {$regex: new RegExp('^' +   $('input:text[name=localBoardTripNumSetting]').val(), 'i')};
    }

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    if($('#localBoardDELDateSetting').val() != ""){
        delDate = moment($('#localBoardDELDateSetting').val(), "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();
        query['delDate'] =  delDate;
    }

    Session.set('QUERY',query);
}
```

That is totally possible.

Comment: I tried this. Was my thought of how to do this.  When I console log the session variable it will have all the appropriate keys but will not have the regex search strings which led me to believe you couldn't have nested object s. To figure that out I console loved the query and the session one after another to see the difference.